# MOSFET PWM switch jamming on - why?

Tags: mosfet, switches, atmega, pwm, driver

[image: Circuit]

The circuit presented here is sized to switch 100W at a minimum pulse width matching 250Hz.  But actually it's currently only being asked to switch around 10-20W.  The load is an array of LEDs.  Q1 and Q2 also have small heat sinks on them for extra measure.

The input circuit actually includes one more BC557 (making the input active-low) and is driven by an Atmega328P PWM output @ 3.3V.

There are two of these circuits (two channels) in a single enclosure, driving remote LED lights.

The lights are part of a solar-powered lighting system, and the lights are often turned on during the day to regulate the charging voltage to the battery.

When this circuit works (which is normally the case) it works very well.

The problem is that occasionally the LEDs are jamming on, eventually draining the battery completely flat.

I'm pretty certain the problem is in this circuit (rather than code), because:

- the condition appears physically very fragile.  Just opening the (normally sealed) enclosure seems to be enough to have the LEDs turn off - as does picking it up and shaking it!  Makes it hard to perform any circuit diagnostics!
- But I can tell (wirelessly) that the Atmega has not rebooted.
- And because both channels have the same fault, it makes me think it's a design flaw and not a component fault or bad connection.
- Also, sticking my fingers all over the circuit (my quick test for high impedance circuitry) doesn't cause the LEDs to react.
- And Q1 and Q2 don't appear to be very hot when in this condition, at least not after being in this condition for a fair amount of time - I've never caught it in the act...

On reflection, R3 could also be smaller.  But I find it hard to believe that's the problem either.

One possible mistake is the lack of a snubbing diode on the load, since the wire lengths are quite long.  But if that was the problem, would I expect to see it turning full-on?

Another mistake could be that I've undersized R1+R2 for suppressing some kind of oscillation?

Another mistake could be not allowing for some kind of thermal event's effect on Q1 and Q2?  Possibly exacerbated by being out in the sun?

I'm sure someone here can tell me what's going on :)

Comment: If the negative (0V) feed is poor (and the layout of the transistors is weak), it could latch on due to volt drops in this feed.

Comment: I have some relatively beefy wire running directly to the MOSFET ground, and everything else is low current.  So I think I have that covered - but it's an interesting possibility...

Comment: I think the problem is probably that I'm flying too close to the wire somewhere in the circuit - perhaps being caught out by some parasitic or thermal effect that I'm naively not considering, but someone more experienced in switching high current loads would...

Comment: I think you should solve this first "the condition appears physically very fragile. Just opening the (normally sealed) enclosure seems to be enough to have the LEDs turn off - as does picking it up and shaking it! Makes it hard to perform any circuit diagnostics!"

Comment: @diverger I'd love to solve that first :)  But I think it's all one and the same.  E.g. if the problem is related to parasitic capacitance then that's also the cause of the physical fragility - opening the enclosure is changing the parasitic capacitance, causing the misbehaviour to collapse.

Comment: I'm very curious, why shaking/picking up can make it not work? Have you some dangling wire in the closure?

Comment: @diverger It's a "prototype" build, but I wouldn't say there's anything dangling or at risk of shorting.  It's all soldered down.  The board itself is not screwed down at this stage though.

Comment: May related to grounding or IF problem. Your entire system is floating right?

Comment: @diverger Yes, system is floating.  Enclosures are plastic.  What kind of scenario do you have in mind?

Comment: You say it "driving remote LED lights", is there a long cable? If there is, have you tried break them, see if your "box" work well without the leds.

Comment: @diverger Yes, one channel is about 10m of LED strip.  The other is driving an LED spotlight, on 5-10m of cable.  I haven't tried interfering with the lights whilst jammed on.  It has only jammed on a handful of times - so reproducing is difficult too!

Comment: My idea is to find what cause the malfunction. If it is the driven part cause the driver malfunction. Or the driver itself has some wrong.

Comment: @diverger The two loads are of very different manufacture, but exhibit very similar behaviour.  A common feature is that they are on a fair length of cable though, so there'd be a bit of induction there.  Hmmm, I guess one channel might even be inducing a voltage on the other channel...

Comment: Show a picture of the construction and precisely how the power feeds make their way to the circuit and how the input exactly feeds to the circuit plus all ground loops you may have that could be taking LED current when they shouldn't be.

Comment: @Andyaka It's probably a bit impractical to convey all that.  It is a prototype, so the build is not awfully rigorous or documented.

Comment: @DavidSainty - you have your answer then! Send the +50 points to charity LOL! PS I think it's a layout problem.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts on whether the fault might be caused by the inductive component of the load, induction between the channels, or possibly that the loads are approximately a small inductor in series with a diode?  I can imagine the problem may be in there - but what I can't figure out is why these aspects might lead to the apparent latching behaviour (I.e. the solution might be to add a snubbing diode to each channel, but I'd still like to understand the reasons why this is happening).

Comment: "And because both channels have the same fault, it makes me think it's a design flaw and not a component fault or bad connection." Having driven the mosfets beyond their SOA once might have damaged both in a similar way. Also you drive both with the same pair of BJTs so if any of those is broken... In any case all people could do here is guessing, to really do more, it would be necessary to do some measurements. Since you say this is a prototype you might be able to solder some cables on that will lead outside and when it hits that condition you can attach a scope?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I should clarify - each channel is a complete and independent duplicate of the above circuit.

Comment: @PlasmaHH At the moment I'm well under-utilising the MOSFETs, so I'd be surprised if they have gone beyond their SOA.  They also aren't obviously damaged - the problem is intermittent, and generally the system performs as designed.

Comment: My current plan is to put a scope on the external loads next time it happens and see if it reveals anything.  But it hasn't happened for a while now...

Comment: Exactly where and how is your "one more BC557" connected? Is it hanging off the +12V supply or off your Atmega's 3.3V supply?

Comment: @brhans Heh, yeah, off the 3.3V rail.  I probably should have included it in the circuit diagram, but I trimmed it off to improve the signal to noise ratio (I think).

Comment: Thanks to everyone for participating in analysing my problem!  The circuit has been stable ever since I raised the question, probably because it's part of a solar system and the weather hasn't been very sunny.  Without a concrete diagnosis it's hard to decide who to give the bounty to.  I would really like to give it to multiple people since I don't actually know yet who is going to be closest to correct, but I've been given a number of avenues to look at, and a fair idea of where not to look.  So I'm awarding it for the very sensible suggestion to incorporate diagnostic LEDs in the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

When using paralleled MOSFETS in the output stage as you are, your should install small ballast resistors (0.2 Ohm) on each source terminal to ground. This will ensure that the MOSFETs share the current equally.

...The way this works is if one MOSFET starts taking more of the current, this will lead to a lowering of the Vgs of that MOSFET which turns the MOSFET off slightly and re-balances the current between MOSFETs.

Also, its best to give each MOSFET its own independent gate resistor, this can eliminate any potential oscillations (at least thats recommended in amplifier circuits with paralleled output transistors).

Comment: I would just put the two of them on a common heatsink and let the natural Rdson positive temperature coefficient take care of balancing. To me, using 200 milliohm resistors to balance the current through 36 milliohm MOSFETs seems like a big power waste, especially if the MOSFETs are up to the task even with imbalance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the code.  When there is over voltage, you are telling it to discharge the battery, but when it is under voltage, you are not telling it to **stop discharging**. If you **are** telling it to stop, then most likely the input is floating (up or down), causing the LEDs to stay on.

Comment: That is the most obvious reason, but I don't think it's code because extremely minor physical interactions (like opening the enclosure) cause the circuit to recover.  There's no reason I can think of why the code would respond to such interactions - so I've rejected this possibility as (probably) unlikely.

Comment: WRT the floating input point, there are pull up/down resistors thoughout.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do several things.

1) Forget parasitics. At the drive levels you're using, these are not going to be a problem.

2) For the love of all that's holy, put in some decoupling capacitance! 10 - 100 uF electrolytic and 0.1 uF ceramic.

3) Put an LED in series with R1, and install it so it is visible outside the enclosure. When your fault condition occurs, you can tell whether it's in the MOSFETs or the gate drive circuitry.

4)When you say that shaking it can fix the problem, is it the shaking? Or is it the touching the case when you pick it up? If it's the latter, it suggests that you don't have a proper ground connection back to your command source.

5) Replace R6 with a 1k, and replace R3 with a 10k. But these are minor.

6) Instead of R5 driving both gates, run a separate resistor to each gate. This shouldn't be critical in this case, but it's good practice.

Comment: There is of course some decoupling on the 3.3V circuit - but not so much near these transistors.  The loads are fed +12V directly from the battery, so decoupling on the +12V rail would primarily be for feeding Q3.  Do you see a potential cause in there?

Comment: I like the LED idea - I should make that permanent :)

Comment: 4. I think it was more than touching the case.  The problem has not reoccurred at any point since raising this question, so I've had no chance to obtain more "test data".

Answer (score 1):

I would change the R1 position to be at right of R2 instead of left as showed in attached schematics, and change its values to 1k.

In this way, when PNP is turned ON, the MOSFETs voltage at gate will be 6 V (12/2) which is enough to fully turn it on. In the original schematics, it's 12 V, and there is no extra benefit at this bigger voltage, on the contrary, there will be more charge stored in the MOSFETs input capacitance.

When PNP is OFF, MOSFET's capacitance can discharge through 1k, and therefore will have a faster discharge than through 1k8+180 in the original schematics. Also, any leakage current from PNP "trying" to charge the MOSFET capacitance will behave better than in the original schematics, as I try to elaborate below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftQuuR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let Ileak be the leakage current from PNP. If we do Thevenin Equivalent analysis from MOSFET gate, with the proposed schematics, the Thevenin voltage will be Ileak·1k and the Thevenin resistance 1000 Ohms. With the original circuit the voltage will be Ileak·1k8 and the equivalent resistance 1980 Ohms. If, for example, the leakage current is 500 uA, the new schematics would be charging the capacitor to 0.5 V (not enough to turn it ON). In the original, while slower, would be charging it to 0.9 (close to turn it ON).

Comment: The reason I placed R1 and R2 that way was to reduce the resistance in the "on" path, whilst leaving the "off" path resistance unchanged.  It seemed a better choice for that reason.  However, when I did the maths I don't think I took leakage current into account, which I should have.  Still, there must be something else going on to turn this into a story about why it jams on.  Perhaps some thermal condition where leakage current remains permanently elevated, or the gate threshold remains permanently lowered...

Comment: Actually, from 1 V or so, the MOSFETs starts to turn ON, so I think that the "off" path should be favored. Could you measure what value would have the current from PNP to the MOSFETs, if the microcontroller stucks the input of the circuit at 0 V?

Comment: It's a good point.  I can check the "off" voltage at the gate tomorrow (unless it's raining :) and see what typical leakage is doing.  I would say though that the LEDs look pretty bright when it's jamming on, it doesn't look like it's at the low end of the linear region...

Answer (score 0):

A couple observations:

1) Is the ground common throughout the design *including* ATMega?  or do you allow a lot of return current to flow through the ground? Voltage drops from high current flow will shift this circuit's voltage relative to the controller.

2) You are **way** over driving the bases on  all the transistors.  Just look at the lower limb of Q3. R1 will have ~ 1 mA flowing through it, this just needs an Ib on Q3 of 50 uA to hit 10 mA Ic.  But you are pulling the base of Q3 hard to ground through R4 (2K) =>~ 6mA.  Look at the values from the Moto data-sheet, page 3 , figure 3.  This will certainly slow it down (but won't cause it to stick).  While you're at Recalculate the values for R4 and R6 and normalize R3 and R5 to the 11K value.

3) The fact that shaking it changes the state may indicate that you have an intermittent short.

Comment: 1. Yes, including the ATMega.

Comment: 2. I'd have to go back and check my maths, but driving the bases hard is intentional in order, ultimately, to drive the MOSFETs hard.  When the channel is on, this means I'm burning quite a bit of current all the way through.  But nowhere near as much as the 100W load I designed it for :)  I think I haven't driven anything out of specification?

Comment: 3. I'm really sure that isn't it...  The two channels both have the same problem.  If it was just one channel going wrong then I'd buy that...

Comment: WRT your first point, I'm pretty sure that the ATMega ground is reasonably solid, because I use its ADC to get the current battery voltage.  I have had problems in the past where the ATMega's ground was being tugged up by current, and in those cases I saw very confusing battery voltage readings.  In this design the battery voltage looks sane.  The MOSFET ground, if anything, should be a little higher than, say, the ground at R1.  But that should make it all the easier for the MOSFET to turn off, so it's hard to see how that might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

As has been said before I'd double check the bias points of the BJTs as they are being driven quite hard, but that shouldn't be an issue. There's a very, very, very remote chance of their parasitic junctions being turned on but the circuit wouldn't recover unless it was powered down and the BJTs would likely be ex-BJTs by that point.

It would be worth taking the gates of the MOSFETs and giving them with separate gate resistors (i.e 180R each) and then connecting to R1 to pull them down. Though it doesn't normally show itself with this kind of power level or bog standard MOSFETs it's perfectly possible to get the gates 'ringing' (i.e. you could be seeing Q1 and Q2 turn on back and forth during the 'stuck on' situation) between each other with their C's and L's along with any inductance lying around the connections and circuit acting as the reactive elements.

As I said, it's a slim chance but easy to try and from a good practice point of view I just wouldn't share gate resistors among MOSFETs.

Comment: I should confess that I've built this on stripboard style board, which makes two parallel MOSFETs easy to do, but two MOSFETs with independent gate resistors somewhat mechanically harder :)  My gut feel has always been that the combined 2k (R1+R2) pull-down for the MOSFETs should be small enough to suppress any ringing - if not immediately then at least eventually.  Is my gut wrong, do you think?

Comment: @DavidSainty Honestly, yes, I'd reckon you're fine. If i were building something similar and i was really worried i would normally pull-down with 1K each but even 10k would do.

The thing to keep in mind for your case is that the pull-up path for those gates is quite strong and you only need ~3mA through Q3 (and therefore R1) before you are going to begin to turn both the FETs on.

The instability of the condition and how easily you say you can disturb it is still making me think it's a somehow capacitive problem (i.e. touching it couples in extra capacitance).